# bitwise not operator 

Tags: java, javascript, c++, c, twos-complement

Why bitwise operation `(~0);` prints -1 ? In binary , not 0 should be 1 . why ?

Comment: If you want to flip a single bit, use `x ^ 1`.

Comment: It's not a 'not' operator. It is a 'complement' operator.

Comment: @EJP: A ***one's*** complement operator.

Comment: No it isn't. The language specification #4.2.2 defines "~" as 'the bitwise complement operator'. There is no such thing in Java as a 'bit operator for NOT'.

Comment: @lh3: No. It's a one's complement operator in both C and C++.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You are actually quite close.

> In binary , not 0 should be 1

Yes, this is absolutely correct when we're talking about one bit.

HOWEVER, an `int` whose value is 0 is actually 32 bits of all zeroes! `~` inverts all 32 zeroes to 32 ones.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(~0));
// prints "11111111111111111111111111111111"
```

This is the two's complement representation of `-1`.

Similarly:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(~1));
// prints "11111111111111111111111111111110"
```

That is, for a 32-bit unsigned `int` in two's complement representation, `~1 == -2`.

---

Further reading:

- [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

  - This is the system used by Java (among others) to represent signed numerical value in bits
- [JLS 15.15.5 Bitwise complement operator `~`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.15.5)

  - "note that, in all cases, `~x` equals `(-x)-1`"

Answer (score 13):

What you are actually saying is ~0x00000000 and that results in 0xFFFFFFFF. For a (signed) int in java, that means -1.

Answer (score 9):

You could imagine the first bit in a signed number to be -(2<sup>x -1</sup>) where x is the number of bits.

So, given an 8-bit number, the value of each bit (in left to right order) is:

```
-128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

Now, in binary, 0 is obviously all 0s:

```
    -128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
0      0  0  0  0 0 0 0 0 = 0
```

And when you do the bitwise not `~` each of these 0s becomes a 1:

```
     -128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
~0      1  1  1  1 1 1 1 1
 =   -128+64+32+16+8+4+2+1 == -1
```

This is also helpful in understanding overflow:

```
     -128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
126     0  1  1  1 1 1 1 0  =  126
 +1     0  1  1  1 1 1 1 1  =  127
 +1     1  0  0  0 0 0 0 0  = -128  overflow!
```

Answer (score 8):

`~` is a bitwise operator.

```
~0 = 1 which is -1 in 2's complement form
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Some numbers in two's complement form and their bit-wise not `~` (just below them):

> 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 127
>    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = −128
>
> 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 = 126
>    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 = −127
>
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 = −1
>    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = 0
>
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 = −2
>    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 = 1
>
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 = −127
>   0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 = 126
>
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = −128
>   0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 127

Comment: +1 for the clear example. Programmers that like to puzzle can find out both how ~ works and how two's complement works just from carefully studying your example!

Answer (score 5):

Because `~` is not binary inversion, it’s bitwise inversion. Binary inversion would be `!` and can (in Java) only be applied to boolean values.

Answer (score 2):

In standard binary encoding, 0 is all 0s, `~` is bitwise NOT. All 1s is (most often) -1 for signed integer types. So for a signed byte type:

```
0xFF = -1    // 1111 1111
0xFE = -2    // 1111 1110
...
0xF0 = -128  // 1000 0000
0x7F = 127   // 0111 1111
0x7E = 126   // 0111 1110
...
0x01 = 1     // 0000 0001
0x00 = 0     // 0000 0000
```

Answer (score 0):

It's binary inversion, and  in second complement -1 is binary inversion of 0.

Answer (score 0):

0 here is not a bit. It is a byte (at least; or more) - 00000000. Using bitwise or we will have 11111111. It is -1 as signed integer...

Answer (score 0):

For 32 bit signed integer

`~00000000000000000000000000000000=11111111111111111111111111111111` (which is -1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the real reason is that ~ is Two’s Complement.

Javascript designates the character tilde, ~, for the two’s complement, even though in most programming languages tilde represents a bit toggle for the one’s complement.