# What's the correct way to flip one bit in a byte while preserving the rest?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

[EDIT]

I realized that unfortunately I oversimplified the question and the answers aren't really helping me, so I'm rephraseing it...

So, my situation I have a stream of incoming bytes (sample) in which the ONLY bit that is potentially set is the first one (0000 | 0001).

So, let's say I get a sequence of these that looks like this:

```
0000,000**0**,
0000,000**1**,
0000,000**0**,
0000,000**1**,
0000,000**0**,
0000,000**0**,
0000,000**0**,
0000,000**0**
```

I'm setting the relevant bit to bold to make it clearer as to what I'm actually collecting.

So, as these 'bits' arrive I need to sort them into something that looks like this:
0000,1010

I'm doing this by shifting the existing value >> 1 and then adding the incoming value shifted over by << 7

```
byte aggregateByte = 0;
//loop 8 times as incoming samples arrive...
aggregateByte = (aggregateByte >> 1) + incomingSample << 7
```

This (*should) produce the correct result.

HOWEVER because java doesn't have the notion of an signed/insigned, EVERY time I shift, because I'm starting on the left hand side, if the previous incoming bit was 1, java PRESERVES the 1 since it sees this as the sign bit and never allows it to reset back to 0.

So... what I need to do prior to adding my incoming bit is to flip the first bit in the existing byte to 0 and then the incoming bit will be set to whatever it needs to be set to.

Currently I'm doing this by setting a mask of 0x7F and &ing that against the byte.

So, my actual addition looks like this:
((aggregateByte >> 1) & 0x7F ) + incomingSample << 7

0x7F creates a mask that looks like this:
0111,111
So, when I & this against the existing value, it flips the last bit to 0.

I guess my question is "am I reinventing the wheel, and is there a better way to handle this, or will this reliably work and is a relatively efficient way to handle this process?"

Comment: Did you try 0x40 to see if it works?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351374/bitwise-operator-for-simply-flipping-all-bits-in-an-integer

Comment: The easiest and most readable way - use a BitSet class. Of course, not as efficient as manipulating a byte array directly.

Comment: You could just use a logical right shift ie `(aggregateByte >>> 1) | (incomingSample << 7)`

Comment: @harold, excellent suggestion! I had overlooked that operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `|` nor `&` is for toggling bits. For that, you need to use `^`. But 0x40 is indeed the correct value for flipping bit 6 ("7th" in your terms).

Comment: @Chris It may be "nicer" but `&` is definitely the wrong operator for the OP, where they need to turn a bit _on_.

Comment: Yup! Just had a re-think. Answer has been deleted.

Comment: I edited my question because I realized that I oversimplified it.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel As harold already mentioned, `>>>` is indeed the correct operator for your case. :-D

Answer (score 3):

To flip bit 3:

```
 final int N = 3;
 b = (byte) (b ^ (1 << N));
```