# Flip all bit values in a byte

Tags: java, byte, bit

I would like to flip all the bits in a byte. How would I do that?

Ex:

```
input:  10101000
output: 01010111
```

Comment: This question has been asked before, try going here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351374/bitwise-operator-for-simply-flipping-all-bits-in-an-integer

Comment: I flagged it as a possible duplicate.

Comment: Use Negate operation. i.e. ~var.

Comment: I realize this is a duplicate now, but I am unable to delet it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`~` bitwise complement operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

```
byte flipped = (byte) ~original;
```

Comment: Or you can do `original ^= 0xFF`, or use `-1` instead of `0xFF`.