# What is the fastest way to inverse bits of a number?

Tags: algorithm

Given a integer number, n. What is the fastest way to inverse bits of that number? For example, if n = 5 (101) then output should be 2(010). Prefix `0` aren't considered for inverse. The unique part of this question is that here, we don't consider prefix `0`.

**My approach**:

```
Convert n to binary as a string. For example, if n = 5 then I'll have string, say str, as `101`.
Convert 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 in the string. (output: 010)
Convert resultant binary string to number. (output: 2)
```

More input/output examples:

```
Input: 7, Output: 0
Input: 8, Output: 7
Input: 10, Output: 5
Input: 98, Output: 29
```

As you can see, my approach looks naive or very inefficient. Is there a better way, by using some bit manipulation operation or any other way get desired output faster?

**Note:** `n` can be negative as well! For negative number, 2's compliment has to be taken in to account for inverting the bits.

I'm not asking for exact code. Pseudo code or approach will be helpful.

Comment: @IVlad `~n` will not work.. I tried it in C# (`uint n = 98;Console.WriteLine(~n);`//output 4294967197) and output wasn't `29`. Probably it will do something to signed bit :|

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitwise operator for simply flipping all bits in an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351374/bitwise-operator-for-simply-flipping-all-bits-in-an-integer)

Comment: You must specify what to do with negative numbers, we can't read your mind.

Comment: It should basically do the same thing. If number is negative then it should inverse it's 2's complement bits

Comment: What about the sign bit ??? What about the 0 prefix ?

Comment: I've said about 0 prefix has to be ignored. In 2's compliment, does sign bit matter? :)

Comment: So you want to take 1's complement of a 2's complement negative number?

Comment: 2's compliment. Editing question to make things clear :)

Comment: Not clear. You want 2's complement in one case and 1's complement in another. Please give a concrete example of what you expect for both a positive number and a 2's complement negative number.

Comment: I want inversion of bits when number is positive. When number is negative, take 2's compliment and then invert it's bits. David's solution is working for me. I'm waiting for better performance solution. :)

Comment: Thank you. That was clearer.

Comment: Your first comment shows an implicit assumption about the "length" of the binary representation of a number (7 bits for 92?): please make that explicit, *especially* for negative numbers. (What do you display as a negative input, anyway?)

Comment: I don't want prefix zeroes to be considered for positive numbers. .Hence you have 7 bits for 92. I want inversion of bits when number is positive. When number is negative, take 2's compliment and then invert it's bits. David's solution is working for me. I'm waiting for better performance solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flip(n) = 2^(ceiling(lg(n))) - 1 - n, where lg is log base 2.

If you know the max set bit of n, then you can quickly get 2^ceiling(lg(n)) by getting the max set bit and shifting 1 to the left by one more.

Comment: So, does `2^ceiling(lg(n))` give max set bit?

Comment: @Abhishek It gets you the max set bit if n is a power of 2; otherwise it gives you the next higher bit because of the ceiling function. E.g., lg(4)=2, lg(8)=3, so ceil(lg(5)) = ceil(lg(6)) = ceil(lg(7)) = ceil(lg(8)) = 3, and 2^3 = 8 = 1000 in binary.

Comment: If n is a power of 2 and you're getting 2^ceiling(lg(n)) via the max set bit, you don't shift, and instead just use 2^ceiling(lg(n)) = 2^lg(n) = n. E.g., if n=8 then n is 1000 in binary and n-1 = 7 = 111, as desired.

Comment: If n is 8, then `2^(ceiling(lg(n)))` is 8. Now, flip(8) = 8 - 1 - 8 = -1. But intended result was 7. How do you handle this scenario?

Comment: Right you are.  Max set bit shifted left 1 will always work. You can take 2^(ceiling(lg(n | 1))) if you want a hacky way to avoid a problem when you're given a power of 2. Alternatively, if n is a power of 2 then n-1 is the answer without doing any work.

Comment: Awesome!! Now, next question would be, how do I quickly decide (without changing time complexity of problem) if n is a power of 2 or not?

Comment: The Bit Twiddling hacks page has a couple algorithms to find the max set bit in O(lg(k)) operations, where k is the number of bits of n (including leading zeroes). The rest is constant time. http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 2):

This problem is interreducible (with the overhead of a bitwise XOR instruction) with the problem of rounding n up to the least number of the form 2^k-1. For a 32-bit int n, you can adapt one of the standard bithacks for the latter:

```
m = n;
m |= m >> 1;
m |= m >> 2;
m |= m >> 4;
m |= m >> 8;
m |= m >> 16;
return m ^ n;
```

Comment: Nice trick. But do I really need to do all those steps to get to 2^k-1? Also, what about negative numbers, will this trick work?

Comment: @Abhishek If you want to handle the full 32-bit range, then yes.

Comment: @Abhishek What do you want to happen for negative numbers?

Comment: Nothing. Your trick work for them as well. I tried with 2's complement notation of negative numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned reversed = 0;
while (num := 0) {
  reversed = reversed << 1;
  reversed |= (num & 1);
  num = num >> 1;
}
```

Shift low order bits out of the original, and or then shift them into successively higher bits in the reversal.

Comment: Not working. Coded it in c# and for input 7, it gave output as 14. It wasn't expected :|

Comment: This appears to reverse the bit string of a number, rather than invert the bits, which is what the question is asking for (unless I'm mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

If performance really matters, you can tabulate.

Process the integer byte by byte from MSB to LSB. If the byte is null, skip. Otherwise use a precomputed lookup table of 256 entries (with prefix), and for the following bytes, XOR.

```
if (B[0]) { B[0]= LUT[B[0]]; B[1]^= 255; B[2]^= 255; B[3]^= 255; }
else if (B[1]) { B[1]= LUT[B[1]]; B[2]^= 255; B[3]^= 255; }
else if (B[2]) { B[2]= LUT[B[2]]; B[3]=^255; }
else B[3]= LUT[B[3]];
```

You can also XOR on 32 bits in a single go, with appropriate masks.

Comment: What is `B` and `LUT`?

Comment: B are the bytes (B[0] assumed MSB, adapt for little-endian), LUT is the lookup-table.

Comment: How will lookup table look like?

Comment: I understand lookup table. I want to know, how will it be generated for current problem?

Comment: Ok. got it. Will try it and get back :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `~n` didn't give you the expected results is all of the leading zeros in your number. To mask those zeros after they are inverted to ones, the straightforward way is:

```
m = abs(n);
result = ~m & (int)(exp2(ceil(log2(m)))-1);
```

This generates a mask of the correct length by taking the base-2 log of the (positive) input. Boundary cases where `n` is a power of 2 are correct because the leading `1` will always be `0` in the result, so its exclusion from the mask doesn't matter.

Performance is probably fair, but coding is concise.