# How to invert binary string and convert to decimal

Tags: rust

I want to invert 12 bit long string representation of binary number and convert it to decimal.

```
let a_str = "110011110101";
let b_str = invert(a_str); // value should be "001100001010"

println!("{}", isize::from_str_radix(a_str, 2).unwrap()); // decimal is 3317
println!("{}", isize::from_str_radix(b_str, 2).unwrap()); // decimal should be 778
```

Comment: You obviously already know how to convert your binary string to a number. Inverting a number bitwise is done with the [`!` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/appendix-02-operators.html?highlight=arith#operators).

Comment: @Jmb ! will convert all the 0s infront of it to 1s which makes it -3318 not 778

Comment: Just mask it to whatever length you want, e.g. `& 0xFFF` for 12 bits (or `& ((1 << n) - 1)` for `n` bits).

Comment: If you want a single operator, you can use XOR (`^ 0xFFF`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bitwise not operator `!` and mask out the unwanted bits:

```rust
let a = isize::from_str_radix(a_str, 2).unwrap();
println!("{a}");
println!("{}", !a & (1isize << a_str.len()).wrapping_sub(1));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=589d840645fae1604cb1ef559fb3e165).

Or you can manipulate the string, but this is much more expensive (allocation and copy):

```rust
let b_str = a_str
    .chars()
    .map(|c| if c == '0' { '1' } else { '0' })
    .collect::<String>();
println!("{}", isize::from_str_radix(a_str, 2).unwrap());
println!("{}", isize::from_str_radix(&b_str, 2).unwrap());
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b7af91cd1ea08866eb915179d1bcc884).